# is_undefined directory error in logack with Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am getting log.dir_IS_UNDEFINED error even though I'm passing log.dir as a java parameter -Dlog.dir="/logs"

Here is a snippet of my logback.xml file

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.dir}/crm.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to switch to Spring Boot logging support. Take a look at configuration section of [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

You can use this:

```
# LOGGING
logging.path=/var/log
logging.file=myapp.log
```

Or you can define it also via system properties:

```
-Dlogging.path=/var/log -Dlogging.file=myapp.log
```

According this section of [Spring Boot Docs about logging with Logback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-logback-for-loggin), you can also use `${LOG_FILE}` and `${LOG_PATH}` environment variables.